# Resolving FK backwards relation when I have a model with two FKs to the same model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm having trouble wiring up a working queryset to obtain all the `Message`s that belong in a chat room. Two users, or `Profiles`, make up a `Pair` object, which should relate to a `Room`--representing a chat room between two people. `Message`s belong within a chat room.

This is the view for a `chat_room` which I attempt to pre-populate with all the previously sent/saved messages:

```
def chat_room(request, slug):
    # a failing queryset
    messages = reversed(request.user.profile.pairing_requester.get(requester=request.user.profile).room.get(occupants=).messages.order_by('-timestamp')[:50])

    return render(request, "chat/room.html", {
        'messages': messages,
    })
```

Going backwards, here are the related models (Message, Room, Pair, Profile):

```
class Message(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, related_name='messages')
    handle = models.TextField()
    message = models.TextField()

    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, db_index=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '[{timestamp}] {handle}: {message}'.format(**self.as_dict())

    @property
    def formatted_timestamp(self):
        return self.timestamp.strftime('%b %-d %-I:%M %p')

class Room(models.Model):
    """
    A room for people to chat in.
    """
    # Unsure whether to have a single FK to Pair, or two directly to Profile
    occupants = models.ForeignKey(Pair, related_name='room')

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    slug = models.SlugField()

    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, db_index=True)

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Pair(models.Model):
    requester = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='pairing_requester')
    accepter = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='pairing_accepter')

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                null=True, blank=True)
```

From my view, how would I obtain all the messages that belong in a room, taking into consideration the two Profiles that the room belongs to?

edit: For what it's worth: I plan on implementing Channels, which I believe affects the decisions regarding fields on the `Room` model. I *don't think* it needs explicit users since a message will be broadcast to a room regardless of who is in it.. Not so sure about this, though.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can a pair be in multiple rooms ?  or a pair is a one to one relationship to the room.

Comment: @SajiXavier a pair cannot be in multiple rooms. A pair of two unique Profiles can only be in one room. Although there can be many different pairs with their own rooms.

Comment: i have updated the answer so check and let me know if it works to your requirements or let me know your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a Pair model, it works with two FK (one for owner and another for the participant) in room.

```
class Room(models.Model):
    """
    A room for people to chat in.
    """
    #  two directly to Profile
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='own_rooms')
    # make it many to many for multiple participants
    participant = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='joined_rooms')

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    slug = models.SlugField()

    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, db_index=True)

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

View Logic

```
def chat_room(request, slug):
    # find all own rooms
    own_rooms = request.user.profile.own_rooms.all()

    # Ideally chat apps displays all the rooms a user is member of and display messages for each rooms. In that case you pass rooms to the template context.

    # same for rooms in which user is participant 
    # find rooms where logged in user is participant
    joined_rooms = request.user.profile.joined_rooms.all()

    # all the rooms where user is owner & participant
    #combine both the rooms
    rooms = list(own_rooms) + list(joined_rooms)
```

Comment: I believe the issue is that "usera" (the opposing chat member) cannot be queried for within this view. Otherwise, your methods would work.   
Sorry--I'll try incorporating again and get back to you. For now, I'm thinking it doesn't work because a Pair can be made of any combination of Profiles. And it is not possible to manually query for a matching pair from within the view--i can only obtain the request.user.

Comment: so you should pass rooms to the template context and display messages for each room. I assumed that you have both the profiles based on the below statement in  your question. "From my view, how would I obtain all the messages that belong in a room, taking into consideration the two Profiles that the room belongs to?"

Comment: Sorry about the confusion--with that statement, I meant that I was having trouble, given that there are two Profiles that I need to account for.  
So you mean pass all of a user's rooms to the template and access the messages through templating?

Comment: yes, because a user can be member of multiple rooms .. So you pass all the rooms to the template and and when user (clicks/access) a room, display all the messages in that room.